# How to raise user notifications in Ubuntu using java code?

Tags: application-development, java

How to raise user notifications in Ubuntu using Java code?

Comment: This is more of a coding question. I found this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987485/make-osd-notifications-via-java

Answer (score 11):

You can use `java-gnome`, a java binding for GTK and GNOME to display notify-osd notifications. You'll need to install the library first:

```
sudo apt-get install libjava-gnome-java libjava-gnome-java-doc
```

Here is a quick example:

```java
import org.gnome.gtk.Gtk;
import org.gnome.notify.Notification;
import org.gnome.notify.Notify;

public class notifyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Gtk.init(args); // initialize Gtk
        Notify.init("Program Name"); // initalize the notification system  

        Notification myNotification = new Notification("Hello world!", "This is an example notification.", "dialog-information"); // create the notification object
        myNotification.show(); // show the notification  

    }


}
```

The general format for a notification is this:

```java
Notification someName = new Notification("Summary", "Body", "Icon")
```

Both the `body` and `icon` fields can be null, but there must be a summary. For a list of icons you can use by default check the [Notify-OSD page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Icon) of the Ubuntu Wiki.

You then call:

```java
someName.show();
```

To display the notification. For more information see the java-gnome [Notify](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/notify/Notify.html) and [Notification](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/notify/Notification.html) doc pages.

> **Note:** You must have both Gtk and Notify initialized before you can send any notifications.

Comment: You should do a selfanswered in SO ;)

Comment: After installing the apt package, how do I add the dependency to my build system (gradle/maven) so I can use it in my code?